# Get Spectrogram from Filtered Power Spectrum

Tags: spectrogram, mfcc, filter-bank

My objective is to get the higher resolution of spectrogram on the high-frequency area (2000 Hz - 5000 Hz) for a section of speech audio. I know that we typically apply Mel-scaled filter bank to get better resolution on lower frequency for speech recognition related tasks. However, in my current work, I want to construct a set of inverse Mel-scaled filter banks to achieve my objective. I have successfully constructed the inverse Mel-filter and applied it to the power spectrum to get inverse MFCC. So I'm a bit lost on this point. How should I get the spectrogram after I applied the inverse Mel-scaled filter to the power spectrum?

Much Thanks,

John